Excel Macro or VBA for Copy and pasting text
I need help writing a macro linked to a keyboard shortcut that says "copy the contents of the cell and add it to the contents of the cell above" e.g copy cell A2 (yacht) and add to contents in cell A1 (cool) so cell A1 will end with text "cool yacht"
Sadly, I don't have any meaningful code knowledge. But I can copy and paste any code to VBA and run it.
This is the result I am getting from recording a macro:
macro result
In plain text:
Sub Macro5()
'
' Macro5 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Sunday Ogundipe"
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
End Sub

The issue is that the macro recorded the whole sample result and will subsequently paste "cool yacht" whenever it is called instead of the variable content of the new cells.

A great way to start a code off is with recording a macro, then trying to adjust it accordingly.

@Excellor I have edited the question with the result from the recorded macro and the issue. Thanks for your time and advice

Great! Now edit it in as plain text, so we can copy it and work on it. (Note that using your sample, we now know where relevant cells are etc.)

I have included the plain text. Please note that the answer I have gotten has solved the issue. You can however continue with this for my educational purposes. Thank you very much.

Try this, it's not using copy/paste, but amends the cell values accordingly:
With ActiveCell
    .Offset(-1, 0).Value = .Offset(-1, 0).Value & " " & .Value
End With

The above will error though, if you run this when active in row 1 as row 0 doesn't exist. So you can check this with:
With ActiveCell
    If .Row > 1 Then .Offset(-1, 0).Value = .Offset(-1, 0).Value & " " & .Value
End With


This worked perfectly. Thank you very much @CLR
